# Some partial animations cannot play as additive in Unity

Tags: animation, bones, unity

I am making a character in Blender and animating it through Unity's Animator Controller.
I have a Base layer in Unity which animates the basic body movements, and an Additive layer which animates the expressions.

The setup is working fine, but something is wrong with some of the partial animations. They get imported into Unity just fine, but will only play as Base-animations or Override animations, *not Additive*. As Override (when they are the only animations playing) they play just fine in Unity.

None of the bones in the expression-animations are referenced in the base/body animations and vice-versa.

At first I thought this was a Unity issue, but I fear it is my Blender animations that are to blame.

Anyone have any ideas or pointers as to why this could be happening?

Best,

/John

Comment: I think this is a Unity problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had no luck getting the additive animations to work. Still have no clue why my head animation won't play as additive, only as override.

I ended up making an Avatar Mask and masked the character's body parts with it.

This way, my "additive" animations can play as Override. Not the perfect solution -- but a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adjusting the transition bar? It's the blue bar that intersects both transitions. The smaller the blue area, the more noticeable second animation. Another possible reason is that you have some of the animations set to atomic, which means they can't be interrupted. Just uncheck atomic and that might fix it as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for giving me some pointers, luigi, but unfortunately, I've already tried both to no avail. It's just as if the figure moves ever so slightly, but almost unnoticeably.

I'm pretty sure, this must be a Blender animation Action issue -- or something about the way I created the animation Actions. From the particular blender file, none of the NEW animations I create work. The old ones do.

I've scrutinized the key frames of all parts of the individual animations in the dope-sheet, but I can't see any difference in the ones that work and the ones that don't.

Comment: I think I had the same problem once with animations not working anymore. Just an fyi, cause some people don't know this, if you save in Blender while in Edit mode it wont update in Unity. You need to be in Object mode. It's possible you're making new animations and saving while in edit mode, which is why the new animations don't work.